# Multiple background videos

Tags: wordpress, video, plugins

I am currently creating a website within Wordpress using the Salient theme. I have managed to include a video into the background using the pre-installed video background feature. This works fine, but is it possible to include multiple videos and show random videos on refresh? Or does anyone know of a plugin to allow this type of feature?

Many thanks in advance!

David.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write some code, you can show random video as background. First you have to create a array of video links something like this:

```
<?php
  $bg = array('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38OUdsf', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38OUdsf' ); // array of video links

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; //  get a random url 
?>
```

And then set the video:

```
  <iframe src="<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is an example of [how to create full page video.](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd)